# PInvoke when you don't know the DLL at compile time?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

In C#, I'm trying to PInvoke a "simple" function I have in C++.  The issue is that I don't know the name or location of the library at compile time.  In C++, this is easy:

```
typedef HRESULT (*SomeFuncSig)(int, IUnknown *, IUnknown **);

const char *lib = "someLib.dll";  // Calculated at runtime

HMODULE mod = LoadLibrary(lib);
SomeFuncSig func = (SomeFuncSig)GetProcAddress("MyMethod");

IUnknown *in = GetSomeParam();
IUnknown *out = NULL;
HRESULT hr = func(12345, in, &out);

// Leave module loaded to continue using foo.
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this in C#.  I wouldn't have any trouble if I knew the dll name, it would look *something* like this:

```
[DllImport("someLib.dll")]
uint MyMethod(int i,
              [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IUnknown input, 
              [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IUnknown output);
```

How do I do this without knowing the dll I'm loading from at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thee is a solution here: [Dynamically calling an unmanaged dll from .NET (C#)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx) (based on LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress)

Comment: Am I missing something? To use LoadLibrary you *do* need to know the name of the dll. If the OP _knew_ the name of the dll he would not try and find a different solution in the first place. Edit: think I missed the "at compile time" vs "at runtime".

Answer (score 7):

You do it the same way.  Declare a delegate type whose signature matches the exported function, just like SomeFuncSig.  Pinvoke LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to get the IntPtr for the exported function, just like you did in C++.  Then create the delegate object with Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer().

Answer (score 1):

If you know the DLL name in advance, and you know the function names in advance, there is a simpler way.

You can simply declare the P/Invoke signatures, then use `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL based on for example a configuration file entry. As long as you successfully call `LoadLibrary` **before** any of the P/Invoke functions are used, they will succeed as the DLL is already loaded.